# how to project a specific field inside a specific index of array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

my query looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('processing_failures').find({"metadata.id": "123", processingFailure: { $size: 5 }})
```

this finds me all the documents that the processingFailure array have 5 elements. but now, i want to project only the element at index 0, and inside element at index 0 i want to see only the "error" field...

cant find how to do this..

this was my try:

```
db.getCollection('processing_failures').find({"metadata.id": "123", processingFailure: { $size: 5 }}, {"processingFailure.0.error"})
```

but didnt work :/